# Trying to bulk update phone number in AD via Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm trying to import and replace telephone numbers in AD via a Powershell script from an exported and updated CSV file.

The script I'm using is:

```
Import-Csv C:\test2.csv | ForEach-Object {
  Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Replace @{
    telephoneNumber=$_.OfficePhone;HomePhone=$_.HomePhone;MobilePhone=$_.MobilePhone}
}
```

The formatting of the CSV is:

```
samaccountname,OfficePhone,HomePhone,MobilePhone
Username,Phone no, phone no, phone no
```

When trying to import it I get the error:

```
C:\Users\account\Desktop\ps2.ps1:2 char:13
+   Set-ADUser <<<<  -Identity $_.samAccountName -Replace @{telephoneNumber=$_.OfficePhone;HomePhone=$_.HomePhone;Mobil
ePhone=$_.MobilePhone}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (1305:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : replace,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I see is that the -Replace operator requires that you use LDAP display fields and MobilePhone does not exist. Use Mobile instead.

Check out [this site](http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm) for a great table listing all the LDAP user attributes. Or you can use the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is considerably less useful because it doesn't show LDAP display names unless you click on links for each field.

Comment: He's got 2 `MobilePhone`s in there:  just for clarification, it's like Karan provided - the first one of the pair needs to be `Mobile`.  But +1 for providing the links to the attribute mapping tables.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine.

```
Import-Csv E:\test.csv | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Replace @{Mobile=$_.MobilePhone}}
```